# Jupyter Lab not opening in ANACONDA due to OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application. How to resolve?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, anaconda3

I use Anaconda to open my Jupyter Lab for code projects for a coding bootcamp. I cannot get my jupyter lab to open when running my dev environment. I have no idea why it's doing this.

The error I get at the end is

> **OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application**

I go through my steps to understand where I went wrong, and this is a basic install with only 1 environment. But here's what I did:

1. I installed Anaconda.
2. I create my environment. In this case a basic dev environment.

> conda create -n dev python=3.7 anaconda

3. Then I activate this dev environment.

> conda activate dev

4. I install jupyter lab package

> conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab

5. I verify jupyter lab installed. It displays jupyterlab and the versions in my screen.

> conda list jupyterlab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvKDU.png)

6. When I run jupyter lab out of my active dev. It errors. It gives all these lines of 'Traceback Errors' I even closed my terminal and re-opened and changed nothing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY2Vk.png)

I verified my anaconda3 folder is installed in my C:/ drive under my USER info. I do everything with Anaconda through my Git Bash. But I did open my Anaconda prompt and ran the commands and got the same result. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for using Jupyter notebook with Firefox browser installed on xenial, including initial installation of jupyter notebook using pip2:

```
sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
pip2 install virtualenv
virtualenv jupyter
source jupyter/bin/activate
pip2 install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

This solution was tested on:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial.
```

It was run on 32bit Chromenotebook.

Jupyter notebook will be open automatically. However, everytime loging in on Jupiter again, at first source needs to be activated:

```
source jupyter/bin/activate
```

and then:

```
jupyter notebook
```

to start.
[image: Firefox and terminal screens]